# How to design a phase selecting switch without using a relay?

Tags: relay, power-electronics, mains, switching, three-phase

My project is an automatic phase switching device which will detect the phase unbalance between the phases and switch the load to the healthiest phase. The block diagram is below:

[image: sample Project blockdiagram]

The project focuses on solving the unbalance created by connecting heavy single-phase loads, like EV chargers and PV inverters to a three-phase supply. The microcontroller detects the healthiest phase and sends a controlling signal to the switching circuit.

We first planned to implement this using relays, but, considering the cost of high-current relays, we dropped it.

We are looking for cost-effective yet reliable switching circuits. Can someone guide me on how to build this switching part?

Specifications of the switch:

1. SPST type
2. Controllable using a microcontroller
3. Three inputs, one output
4. 40 A current handling capacity at continous conduction

Comment: What actually is the load? How will it handle being supplied a potentially chopped-up supply with all the nasty transients and inrush currents associated with switching between phases in a non-synchronous manner? I smell big trouble with this design and, I smell massive inrush currents beyond the 40 amps mentioned.

Comment: The load is EV chargers. This is the block diagram of just the switching part only. This is just an interface between the supply and charger. Rest all will be compensated by EV charger.

Comment: What is your target cost? How much are the contractors/ relays that you have found so far ?

Comment: Target cost is below 50$. We need total of 3 relays , as per our preliminary design. Each cost around 28-35 dollar . We are looking for alternative approaches , other than relays

Comment: I’m surprised that ev chargers are not three phase in a place where three phase is common. Interesting project though.

Comment: Yes EV chargers and PV inverters are single phase loads in our place. There is a specific model of ev which uses 7.5kW charger which asks the consumer to apply for a 3Phase connection but the charger is still single phase.